# Mixed Groovy/Kotlin DSL multiproject build, How can Kotlin read ext variables

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I'm exploring converting our Groovy DSL based build files to Kotlin and would like to do this incrementally.  However, I can't figure out how to read `ext` variables set in the top level `build.gradle` in a sub-project `build.gradle.kts`.

My experimental repository is available [here](https://git.sr.ht/%7Eamyers/gradle-mixed-mode-test)

It has this layout:

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── groovy
│   └── build.gradle
├── kts
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── xyz
│                   └── abc
│                       └── def
│                           └── Main.java
└── settings.gradle
```

The top level file defines an `ext` variable containing common library versions like so:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

ext.libraries = [ shared: "xyz.abc.def:art:1.2" ]
```

There are two sub-projects, one using the Groovy DSL and one using the Kotlin DSL.  They both attempt to declare a dependency on `libraries.shared`.

```
╰─➤  cat groovy/build.gradle 
plugins {
    id("java")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libraries.shared)
}

╰─➤  cat kts/build.gradle.kts 
plugins {
    id("java")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libraries.shared)
}
```

`settings.gradle` includes both projects.

```
╰─➤  cat settings.gradle 
include "groovy"
include "kts"
```

When I run `./gradlew projects` I get this error:

```
  Line 6:     implementation(libraries.shared)
                             ^ Unresolved reference: libraries
```

When the include for the `kts` sub-project is commented out it succeeds, displaying the `groovy` sub-project.

I've tried a number of different things to reference the `libraries`, such as `project.extra` or `extra` but so far haven't hit anything that works.

EDIT:

After digging around in the Gradle API docs I came up with this, which works but is absolutely horrid.

```kotlin
implementation((project.getParent()!!.extra.properties["libraries"]!! as HashMap<String, String>).get("shared")!!);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this in the kotlin script

```
plugins {
    java
}

val libraries: Map<String, String> by rootProject.extra

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libraries["shared"]!!)
}
```

#### Edit

If you are using a current (7 at time of writing) version of Gradle, you could try out the new version catalogues feature -- which is in preview at time of writing, so may be a bumpy road to take...

To do this, you can remove your `ext.libraries` from your root project, and replace it with this in `settings.gradle`

```
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            alias('shared').to('com.bloidonia:ascii-image:1.1')
        }
    }
}
```

Then in both Groovy and Kotlin DSL build scripts, you can reference these dependencies via:

```
    implementation(libs.shared)
```

#### Edit 2 -- after some coffee

Ahhh, so I think this answers Jeff's question in the comments, and shows an alternative

Yes, we could add a function to ext in the root Project like so:

```
ext.libraries = [ shared: "com.bloidonia:ascii-image:1.1" ]
ext.library = { String name ->
    ext.libraries."$name"
}
```

And then in the Kotlin project, we can do:

```
val library: groovy.lang.Closure<String> by rootProject.extra

dependencies {
    implementation(library("shared"))
}
```

Comment: Clean answer. :) Instead of `libraries["shared"]!!` people like me wishing to avoid the double-bang (`!!`) may also use `libraries.getValue("shared")`.

Comment: I like it.  I wish there was a built in API for this, but this is more explicit about where these are coming from, which I appreciate.

Comment: A built in API is in preview atm with https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:type-safe-project-accessors and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies

Comment: Does this work when defining the variable in a `build.gradle` at the project's top level (honest question, I don't know)?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown added a bit about the preview version catalog feature in Gradle 7.  If you're asking about the original question, then so long as the value is defined in `extra` (`ext` in Groovy) in the top level script, yes this is how you can get at it from a sub-module...  I have a feeling I'm not 100% understanding the question though :-(

Comment: @JeffScottBrown actually, now I'm more awake, I think "_Edit 2_" may be more aligned with the question 

Comment: Does the first snippet under *Edit 2* work if that is in the root level `build.gradle`?

Comment: I cannot make this work and am trying to understand what the issue is.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Pushed https://github.com/timyates/gradle-root-level-groovy-from-kotlin-dsl to show what I have for this...  My guess is I'm doing something wrong if it's not working for you 

Comment: "My guess is I'm doing something wrong if it's not working for you" - I expect that isn't the case.  If it is working for you, it works.  ;). Thanks for the feecback.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  "works on my machine" is never very satisfying  let me know if you find a mistake ... Maybe gradle version is coming in to play? 

Comment: "Maybe gradle version is coming in to play?" - it is possible, but I don't think so.  I think what you have works.  I think I had omitted `val library: groovy.lang.Closure<String> by rootProject.extra` and that is likely required.  Thanks again!